# TypeError: Cannot read property 'current' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, command, discord.js

I just made a weather command for discord.js, it works fine but if I run `p!weather 'not a city'` it'll give me an error, I can't find any mistakes in my code, does anyone knows how to fix it. I am using slappy/discord.js. This is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const weather = require("weather-js");

module.exports = class WeatherCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('weather', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!message.guild) return message.channel.send(`Try again if you are in a server channel!`);
    const city = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
    if (!city) return message.channel.send("I need a city to check :wink:")

    weather.find({search: city, degreeType: 'C'}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            message.channel.send("**${arg}** Isnt inside my query, please check again")
            console.log(err.stack)
            return;
        }
        let url;
        if (result[0].current.skytext === "Mostly Sunny") url = "https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/3367/ivak-Decorative-Sun.png"
        else if (result[0].current.skytext === "Mostly Cloudy" || result[0].current.skytext === "Cloudy") url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Weather-heavy-overcast.svg/200px-Weather-heavy-overcast.svg.png"
        else if (result[0].current.skytext === "Partly Cloudy") url = "";
  
        var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Forecast for ${result[0].location.name}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .addField("Temperature", `**${result[0].current.temperature}ºC**`, true)
        .addField("Humidity", `**${result[0].current.humidity}%**`, true)
        .addField("Wind Speed", `**${result[0].current.windspeed.replace("mph", "ms/h")}**`, true)
        .addField("Feels Like", `**${result[0].current.feelslike}ºC**`, true)
        .addField("Status", `**${result[0].current.skytext}**`, true)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setThumbnail(result[0].current.imageUrl)
        .setColor('YELLOW')
        .setFooter(`Requested by: ${message.author.tag}`)
        message.channel.send({ embed: embed })
})};
}
```

thanks

Comment: The issue is that you don't check the contents of `result` inside of `weather.find`, so `result[0]` can be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The bot can't read the property of `current`. You used `current` after `results[0]`, which means that that's undefined. I suggest logging `results` to see what's in it to know how to get your desired data.